# Mongoose $match any value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Based on user input I want to search my db for documents where the type is one of several values. If the input is equal to 'any', I want to it to return documents where the type is equal to anything.

My $match is part of an aggregate pipleline. I just want to do something like this, where the value I set to inputType will cause the $match to return all documents regardless of their type value.

```
 if (inputType == 'any')
 inputType = '*';

{"$match": { 
  type: inputType, 
}}
```

Is there anything like this? Or perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: How about: `{ $match: { $or: [ { type: "type1" } , { type: "type2"} ] }}`...or just return the whole collection

Comment: I was hoping to change just the variable, and only for 'all'. This way I think i'd have to change the variable for every other 'type' to be an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
if (inputType === 'any') {
  inputType = {
    $exists: true
  };
}

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { 
      type: inputType, 
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that you could use regular expressions. This does the job:

```
inputType = /.*/g;
```